# "Have/has" vs. "of"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Given "the account that has the number 45823", can we replace the *has* with *of* to get "the account number of 45823"? And what about "the account of the number 45823"?

I could not find this in any dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Of' in that context does not mean what you want it to mean!
You can say: "*the account number 45823*", but saying "*the account number of 45823*" will not imply what you want it to.
Saying that would imply "*the account number which is possessed by '45823'*", which is not what you mean to say, is it?

Again, "*the account of the number 45823*" implies "*the account which is **possessed** by the **number 45823***, which is not the case. It is the **account** which possesses the account number.

And why not 'has'? 
One meaning of 'has' is '*posesses*'. So saying:

> "The account which has the (account) number 45823..."

is correct.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yeah, it isn't and I realised that it came out wrong while typing it. Which is why I edited it. :)

Comment: @RegDwigнt what is the completeley different meaning?

Comment: @hawk I've edited my answer, the meaning is there :)

Comment: @hawk these are all very basic questions that are better suited for our sister site for English Language Learners, which is where I am migrating this question now.

Comment: @ЯegDwight still waiting for answer explains the difference between them

Comment: I don't think "waiting" means what you think it means. (^_^)

Comment: `Again, "the account of the number 45823" implies "the account which is possessed by the number 45823, which is not the case. It is the account which possesses the account number` This is what I was looking for. Thanks